# html form submission - javascript does not submit input button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Here's the problem: I have a simple form with three buttons and some hidden input fields. Depending on the button pressed (different name="" values), the action does something different.
I am now trying to add a confirmation dialog box to this form by doing this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/action" onsubmit="return confirmFormSubmit(this);">
    <input type="submit" name="one" value="This">
    <input type="submit" name="two" value="That">
    <input type="submit" name="three" value="Something else">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmFormSubmit(obj)
{
    window.event.preventDefault();
    jConfirm('Are you sure you want to do this?', 'Awaiting confirmation', function(r) {
        if (r == true) {
            obj.form.submit();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

When I click OK, the action happens, but the input button is not submitted.
Doing 'document.location = obj.form.action;' is not an option because that will not submit the POST parameters.

How can I make the damn thing submit the input fields and not just call the action?

Comment: what does your "/action" action (sorry for this :P) actually do?

Comment: Changes an entity's status or deletes it. What does it matter anyway? That's already server-side.

Comment: @Samuele - Why, it runs the action, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is because the onsumit method overrides the action in your form declaration.
I would actually change the button of the form and make it a button linked to a javascript method that performs required tests and submit values to the right action.

Comment: There are no tests, I only need it to submit the POST variables, all of which, except the submit button, are the same...

Answer (score -1):

```
<form method="POST" action="/action">
    <a href="javascript: confirmFormSubmit(this)">
        <input type="button" name="three" value="Something else">
    </a>
</form>
```

something like this should be working

Comment: -1 why, actually? dude, try it, you don't use the form submit / onsubmit, but you call a javascript method that handles the submit for you. it's actually working. so, before anything else, try it.

Comment: Sorry I'm writing 2 years later, but I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer, though I can see why someone would do that.